# Sapply row means

Tags: r, matrix, sapply

new here on stackoverflow!

Here's the problem:

assignment is to create following matrix and count row means by using sapply

```
A <- matrix(121:180, nrow=6)
```

Been trying to solve this for hours now with no luck. It's easy to use `apply`, or `rowMeans`, but `sapply` seems to be tricky..Is it even possible? Any tips?

Comment: When you say that to create following matrix, what are the rules?  If it is just to make a matrix, what is wrong with your approach?

Comment: If you have an assignment to do this with sapply, you really should show us some of what _you_ have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sapply on the matrix indices:

```
sapply(1:nrow(A), function(i) mean(A[i, ]))
```

But you should use rowMeans instead, since it is simpler and faster.